# Consume enum from ambient TypeScript module using @babel/preset-typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums, babeljs

Is it possible to consume an `enum` from a file being transpiled by `babel` using `@babel/preset-typescript`?

`mymodule.d.ts`

```
declare module 'mymodule' {
  export enum Fruit {
    apple = 'Apple',
  }
}
```

`script.js`

```
import { Fruit } from 'mymodule'

assert.equals(Fruit.apple === 'Apple')
```

`Fruit` will be undefined in this case since `babel` does not know about the ambient declaration.

Is there a way to get around this besides declaring a separate enum/constants file and directly importing those in both places (the ambient module and the script)?

Comment: does the module you are declaring exist? Because the declaration is just a lie...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot import executable code from a declaration file (`*.d.ts`).

You can use a declaration file to *describe* what's happening in another module. In this case, if `Fruit` exists in `mymodule` you could declare its shape in `mymodule.d.ts` — but it's not the declaration that's executed, but the actual code living in `mymodule`.

In other words, `Fruit` must exist in a `*.ts` or `*.js` file in order to be used in runtime.